# Can we add an "other off-site resources" term to the recommendation close reason?

Tags: feature-request, closing

The current close reason for asking for recommendations is

> Questions that ask for recommendations of games, software, or hardware are off topic.

I think this is too specific. We should also be closing questions asking for websites, products, videos, and other things. So I suggest changing to the following

> Questions that ask for recommendations of games, software, hardware **or other off-site resources** are off topic.

This is similar to Stack Overflow's rule, and would reduce the number of edge cases when dealing with recommendation questions.